# DELETE FROM x LEFT JOIN y WHERE x.a IS NOT NULL IN table y

Tags: mysql

How do you delete records from table A that do not exist in table B?

I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM
    x
LEFT JOIN
    y
ON
    x.image_hash IS NOT NULL IN y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` clause appropriately.

`DELETE FROM x WHERE <NOT> EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM y WHERE y.<something> = x.<some_column> AND <some more conditions>`